# Building asp.net MVC application in VSTS

Tags: c#, build, nuget, azure-devops

I have been using Visual Studio Online for my MVC application for a while now, but I have only been using it mainly as a way to manage my work, cloud storage and version control in case I need rollback something that I made a mistake on.

It has gotten to the point in time where I need to start managing my releases properly rather than just managing it in a folder structure. (I know, I am fairly unprofessional).

So, I am trying to use CI in VSTS but all of my builds are failing. It seems that I am missing all of my NuGet packages. Here is the log from my **NuGet restore**

https://hastebin.com/ufibohoqir.tex

I have read up a bit on a `nuget.config` file, which I don't have. I have tried to research into this but I am fairly lost. Do I need this file? I don't use any other packages except for nuget.

Any help would be appreciated. I use VS2015, and I can build using it. I have no idea why it can not find the nuget references.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the Log of the build that failed. https://file.io/cRydzZ

It was too big to put the whole thing on Hastebin. Bu, here is a snippet of the log of when it started to break.

https://hastebin.com/ubofozirop.vbs

**EDIT 2**

After changing my **Agent Queue** to *Hosted*, as was suggested, the NuGet packages all seem to be restored successfully. The build is still failing though. Here is my .csproj file: https://hastebin.com/iravicayek.xml

One of the things that I have noticed is that the packages that are not found when building are the ones that look like this in the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

All of the ones that don't have `HintPath` and `Private` elements as children seem to load. I tested to see if I removed the children from the `Reference` elements, but they still failed to build.

Comment: If your build is failing up then it would be nice if you put log file generated during that build. Nuget restore seems to be successful so problem is some where else.

Comment: @dotnetstep The nuget doesn't fail because it can't find anything. It keeps saying that things are missing. Here is the logfile - https://file.io/cRydzZ. It was too big to put on Hastebin. I am going to put the file link in the question as well as a Hastebin of a snippet of when it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the reason why you can not the `nuget.config` file used for NuGet restore task, is caused you were use Hosted VS2017 agent.

If you want to build your project with VS2015 on hosted agent, please use **Hosted agent** (which installs VS2015) instead of Hosted VS2017 agent (which does not install VS2015).

Besides, if the build still fails with missing reference, please check the path for the referenced packages in the `.csproj` file.

---

The path for the Antlr3.Runtime package in your project file also seems incorrect. Please change the Reference for the Antlr3.Runtime package as below and then try again:

```
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr3.Runtime.3.5.1\lib\net40-client\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I added my .csproj file under EDIT 2 as well as some extra info after changing the agent to Hosted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My Antlr3.Runtime is not incorrect.

Comment: So what's other problems do you still meet?

Comment: The exact same issues. There has to be some part that I am not understanding or maybe i am not explaining my issue well enough. I have no idea why it can't find all these references when it tries to build in Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Can you share your project (or an example project which can reproduce the error) in one drive?